# UIMenuController not appearing after change of view

Tags: iphone, ios, uimenucontroller

I have a UIMenuController which is presented when a UIView is tapped. I have implemented the canPerformAction and canBecomeFirstResponder methods, and it works when the view is first loaded. The app is navigated by a tab view, and if a user is to switch to another view and then back to the first (although the same issue occurs if a modal view is presented from the first view), the UIMenuController will no longer show up. Any ideas as to why this could be?

Answer (score 2):

I just worked out the answer: I have to manually call becomeFirstResponder on my view in order for it to work.