# UIMenuItem not appearing after switching to other tab

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uimenuitem

I have been implemented an UIMenuItem to show by long-pressing an item on a TableViewController that is an element of a UITabBarController.
 I did that like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    resendMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Kirim Ulang" action:@selector(resend:)];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems: @[resendMenuItem]];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] update];

} 

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    return (action == @selector(resend:));
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    return YES;
}


-(BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    return (action == @selector(resend:));
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

/// this methods will be called for the cell menu items
-(void) resend: (id) sender
{
 // do something
}
```

Initially the menu appears well. However after switching to other tab in a UITabBarController then switch back again to UITableViewController, the menu becomes not to appear if i long-press it. Why?

Comment: what happens if you move your code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear? I am guessing somethings gets knocked off when you switch tabs, and since the viewcontroller is loaded, your UIMenuController is not expecting to be shown.

Comment: I'm still waiting for other answers..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Found solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13096016/536241): You have to call becomeFirstResponder in the viewDidAppear of your UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement following `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method:

Swift:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    viewController.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [viewController becomeFirstResponder];
}
```